# Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4608m

Tags: java, android, flutter, release

When I try to build a release apk I faced this problem:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4608m Invalid maximum heap size:
> -Xmx4608m The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal
> exception has occurred. Program will exit.

and my gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have tried to change `org.gradle.jvmargs` value to -Xmx512M but I faced this problem too:

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> > Java heap space

flutter doctor result:

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19042.1237], locale en-150) [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0) [√] Chrome - develop for
> the web [!] Android Studio (not installed) [√] VS Code (version
> 1.60.2) [√] Connected device (2 available)

Comment: What Java version are you using? Also, are you by any chance using a 32bit version?

Comment: I'm using 'openjdk version "11.0.8-internal" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8-internal+0-adhoc..jdk11u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8-internal+0-adhoc..jdk11u, mixed mode)'
and I have 64-bit OS.

Comment: @akortex did you understand anything?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error, it seems that you're unable to use the configured heap size. Possible causes of this issue is if you're using a 32-bit JVM. You can try using a heap size lower than 4GB. If you're using Android Studio, you can follow this [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#adjusting_heap_size) to change the max heap size.